# How to use if-else statements in sweave documents

Tags: r, sweave

Is there a way to use an if-else statement in an sweave document, so that a figure is only shown depending on the value of an R object. I tried different approaches (two of them are below), but I did not find a solution that is working.

Alternative 1:

R-Code:

```
x <- seq(0, 10, length.out=11)
y <- seq(0, 10, length.out=11)
show_figure <- sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), 1)
```

Latex-Code:

```
...
<<fig = show_figure, echo = FALSE>>=
plot(x,y)
@
...
```

Alternative 2:

R-Code:

```
...
figure <- if(show_figure) {
             "<<fig = TRUE, echo = FALSE>>=
             plot(x,y)
             @"
          } else {}
```

Latex-Code:

```
...
\Sexpr{figure}
...
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use a LaTeX conditionals for this. LaTeX simply do not know nothing about the R code and simply typeset the output of R. But you can use a R conditional:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
<<echo=F,results='asis'>>=
    x <- seq(0, 10, length.out=11)
    y <- seq(0, 10, length.out=11)
    show <- sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), 1)
    if(show==TRUE){plot(x,y)} else{cat("No plot,sorry")}
@
\end{document}
```

This produces randomly a PDF with a scatterplot or only the warning "No plot, sorry".